# SNMP on AIX 5.3

Tags: aix, snmp

I need to monitor a system with AIX 5.3, but can't find a good source for the OIDs.
Does anybody know the OIDs for CPU, Memory and Harddisk values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find which OIDs have the numbers you want is to use a tool like [snmpwalk](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpwalk.html).

However, I think the defaults should be something like this:

CPU: 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.Index

Storage Types: 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.2.Index

Storage Size:  1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.5.Index

Storage Usage: 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.6.Index

It is also helpful to read the RFC's for SNMP, [RFC1157](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1157.txt), [RFC2571](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2571.txt), [RFC2790](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2790.txt)